# Adding combo box value to datagrid column filled by SQL

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Struggling to find an answer on this one. I have a Windows app, on which an operator scans a barcode and the app returns some information based on the barcode from a SQL database. This then adds a row to a DataGridView control.

I've been asked to make a change - on the same form is a combo box control with 4 statically configured values. What I need to have happen is when the operator scans the barcode and the new row is added to the DGV control, the last column in the DGV needs to be filled with the selected item of the CB control.

Screenshot A: what the DGV looks like after scanning a barcode presently:

[image]

Screenshot B: what I want to achieve; notice the TestPanel column text matches the Panel combo box contents:

[image]

Most of the answers I found when searching suggested adding the data to the datatable before the DGV is filled - I've tried a few suggestions across the internet with no joy. Not sure if that's just the wrong solution or I'm doing something wrong.

I also gave the below a try but thinking it does not work because the DGV is populated via a Datatable.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In GetResults_Meth().Rows
  dgScanned.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
  Dim test As String = cbPanel.SelectedItem
  dgScanned.Columns(8).ToString().Replace(" ", test)
Next dr
```

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of information. There are are 9 columns in the DGV with one hidden, 8 of the columns are populated by the SQL query:

```
Public Sub frmLASend_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dgScanned.ColumnCount = 9
        dgScanned.Columns(0).Name = "Request ID"
        dgScanned.Columns(1).Name = "GivenName"
        dgScanned.Columns(2).Name = "Surname"
        dgScanned.Columns(3).Name = "DOB"
        dgScanned.Columns(4).Name = "Sex"
        dgScanned.Columns(5).Name = "Specimen"
        dgScanned.Columns(6).Name = "Referral Date"
        dgScanned.Columns(7).Name = "IgnoreMe"
        dgScanned.Columns(7).Visible = False
        dgScanned.Columns(8).Name = "TestPanel"

        cbPanel.Items.Add("Amino Acids")
        cbPanel.Items.Add("MACS")
        cbPanel.Items.Add("Methylation")
        cbPanel.Items.Add("Organic Acids")
        cbPanel.SelectedItem = "Amino Acids"
```

Each barcode scan only produces one result from the database and hence only adds a single row to the DGV. So the operator will scan all barcodes relating to the task which will appear in the DGV.

SQL query:

```
Private Function GetResults_Meth() As DataTable

        Dim dtResults_Meth As New DataTable
        Dim connString As String = "Data Source=NP-SQL03\SQL2019;Initial Catalog=asl;User Id=aslmanager;Password=!_asl1_!"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("
                SELECT DISTINCT requests.request_id AS 'Request ID', patients.first_name AS GivenName, patients.surname AS Surname,
                concat(patients.day_birth, '/', patients.month_birth, '/', patients.year_birth) AS DOB, patients.sex AS 'Sex',
                specimens.specimen AS 'Specimen', referral_details.referral_dt AS 'Referral Date', labs.lab_name
                
                FROM
                { oj (((((((asl.dbo.requests requests INNER JOIN asl.dbo.requests_services requests_services ON
                requests.request_id = requests_services.request_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.referral_details referral_details ON
                    requests.request_id = referral_details.referring_request_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.patients patients ON
                    requests.patient_id = patients.patient_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.specimens specimens ON
                    requests_services.specimen_id = specimens.specimen_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.referral_details_services referral_details_services ON
                    requests_services.request_id = referral_details_services.request_id AND
                requests_services.service_id = referral_details_services.service_id)
                
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.labs labs ON referral_details.to_lab_id = labs.lab_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.services services ON referral_details_services.service_id = services.service_id)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN asl.dbo.addresses addresses ON labs.lab_address_id = addresses.address_id}

                WHERE
                    referral_details.referral_dt >= @StartDate AND
                    referral_details.referral_dt <= @EndDate AND
                    labs.lab_id = '82' AND
                    requests.request_id = @LabID AND
                    services.service_abbrev IN ('SAMe', 'SAHe', 'THF', 'Folinic', '5MTHF', 'GluthR', 'Gluthox')

                GROUP BY
                    requests.request_id, patients.first_name, patients.surname,
                    patients.month_birth, patients.day_birth, patients.year_birth,
                    patients.sex, services.service_abbrev, specimens.specimen,
                    referral_details.referral_dt, requests.collection_dt, labs.lab_name
                
                ORDER BY
                    labs.lab_name ASC,
                    requests.request_id ASC

                ", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTo.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LabID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtBarcode.Text
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dtResults_Meth.Load(reader)



Process:
                    If dtResults_Meth.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("This Lab ID cannot be added to the manifest because it is not in the referrals table or is not being referred for this panel. Please resolve and try again.", "No Referral", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Else


                        Return dtResults_Meth


                    End If
                Catch Ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to SQL Server. Please check your network connection and if required, report the issue to IT." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Ex.Message, "No Connection!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End Using

        End Using


    End Function
```

Trigger (carriage return after the barcode):

```
Private Sub txtBarcode_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtBarcode.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If txtBarcode.Text.Length < 7 Or txtBarcode.Text.Length > 7 Then
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("specierror.wav")
                MessageBox.Show("Scanned Lab ID is invalid. Please try again.", "Invalid Lab ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Else
                If cbPanel.SelectedItem = "Methylation" Then

                    If GetResults_Meth() Is Nothing Then
                    Else
                        For Each dr As DataRow In GetResults_Meth().Rows

                            'Ignore the below. Was tinkering
                            dgScanned.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
                            Dim test As String = cbPanel.SelectedItem
                            dgScanned.Columns(8).ToString().Replace(" ", test)

                        Next dr
                        txtBarcode.Text = ""
                        txtBarcode.Focus()
                    End If
                ElseIf cbPanel.SelectedItem = "Organic Acids" Then

                    If GetResults_OrgA() Is Nothing Then
                    Else
                        For Each dr As DataRow In GetResults_OrgA().Rows

                            dgScanned.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)

                        Next dr
                        txtBarcode.Text = ""
                        txtBarcode.Focus()
                    End If
                ElseIf cbPanel.SelectedItem = "MACS" Then

                    If GetResults_MACS() Is Nothing Then
                    Else
                        For Each dr As DataRow In GetResults_MACS().Rows

                            dgScanned.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)

                        Next dr
                        txtBarcode.Text = ""
                        txtBarcode.Focus()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: You say that a row is added to the grid when the user scans a barcode but you don't seem to have actually showed us that code. You've shown us a loop that would generally be used to add multiple rows to the grid. Is it actually the case that you're adding multiple rows to grid using that loop from data retrieved from the database based on the barcode scanned by the user?

Comment: The data being added to the grid appears to be coming from a `DataTable`. How many columns in that `DataTable` and how many in the grid? Does the `DataTable` contain a column that corresponds to this value coming from `ComboBox` or not?

Comment: This line doesn't make sense: `dgScanned.Columns(8).ToString().Replace(" ", test)`. That whole expression is not going to change anything anywhere. It's going to return a `String` but you don't do anything with it, so nothing happens. If you expect that value to be displayed in the grid, you'd need to display it in the grid, wouldn't you?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Your comments made me realise I should have added the code snippets - Question has been edited and hopefully answers your questions now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the crux of the issue is that you're populating the grid from the `DataTable`, then you getting some data back from the grid and trying to change, then failing to put the result back in the grid. The obvious solution is to modify the data in the `DataTable` or even putting the actual data you want in the `DataTable` in the first place.

I don't know how that `GetResults_Meth` is written but one option is to put the `ComboBox` value directly into your query, so it gets added to the `DataTable` at the outset, e.g.

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT Column1, @Column2 AS Column2 FROM SomeTable"

'...

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = myComboBox.Text
```

The text from the `ComboBox` will now be in every row of the result set of the query.

The other option is to modify the data in the `DataRow` first, then add the data from the `DataRow` to the grid. Going from your own code:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In GetResults_Meth().Rows
    dr(8) = cbPanel.Text

    dgScanned.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
Next dr
```

Based on your images though, it looks like you want column index 7, not 8.

Comment: And of course it was that simple. Thank you @jmcilhinney for your answer, that is doing exactly what I need. I went with your second example as I understood it better.